Process eleventy shortcodes in markdown-rendered FrontMatter data
I'm using 11ty with Decap CMS for a client webiste.
I have several front-matter fields to add markdown content (I need to add Markdown content to boxes in several locations) .
I render the markdown content using a markdown-it filter. This is working very well.
However I also implemented shortcodes, for example to add YouTube iframes within the markdown. The shortcode render without a problem when they are in the markdown body, but not if they are in the front matter.
How to make sure they are rendered too?
CURRENT SETUP
.eleventy.js
// my youtube shortcode 


    //YouTube embed 
    eleventyConfig.addNunjucksShortcode("youtube", (classes, videoURL, title, caption) => {
        const url = new URL(videoURL);
        const id = url.searchParams.get("v");
        var caption= mdSetup.render(caption);
 
        return `
        <figure class= "${classes}">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/${id}" title="${
          title ? ` for ${title}` : ""
        }" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer;  clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope;  web-share" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <figcaption class="caption">
        <span class="wrapper">${caption}</span>
        </figcaption>
        </figure>
        `;
      });

// to process markdown 
 eleventyConfig.addFilter("in_markdownify", (markdownString) =>
        mdSetup.renderInline(markdownString)
    );


My .md file with YAML front matter
---
title: Testing Image Compression
layout: layouts/banners.njk
banners:
  - bg:
      - label: White Background / Purple text
        name: whitebg
    imgstyle:
      - label: Green text / Purple Shadow
        value: img-green
    id: banner1
    boxes:
      - type: dc-box
        left: Test
        right: >
          {% youtube "Class" , "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JC7MNybwnTA" , "Comment" , "Caption" %}

          
          ## MARKDOWN
---

template .njk
<div class="doublec-box text">

        <div class="leftc">
     {{ box.left | markdownify | safe}}
        </div>
        <div class="rightc">
     {{ box.right | markdownify | safe}}
   
        </div> 

</div>

My html output
<div class="doublec-box text">
  <div class="leftc">
     <p>Test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightc">
     <p>
     {% youtube “undefined” , “<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JC7MNybwnTA">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JC7MNybwnTA</a>” , “Dead White man’s Clothes x Atmos” , “” %}
     </p>
     <h2 id="markdown" tabindex="-1">MARKDOWN</h2>
  </div> 
</div>
 

My expected output: rendered shortcode into youtube iframe

<p><figure class= "undefined">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/JC7MNybwnTA" title=" title" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer;  clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope;  web-share" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<figcaption class="caption">
<span class="wrapper"></span>
</figcaption>
</figure></p>


The problem is that mdSetup.renderInline is just converting markdown to html, without running it through the Nunjucks templating language which you use for the shortcode. But I'm not an 11ty export, so not sure whether there is a function to treat a string as a template...

Yes, I agree that is the problem, but i also don't know how to solve it. Thanks

I have tried using the renderTemplate shortcode, as documented here but It do'esn't seem to work to process
in my .njk
{% renderTemplate "njk", box %}

 {{ box.left}}

{% endrenderTemplate %}

outputs nothing.

I think that function is only usable inside templates. Anyway, if you cannot get the shortcodes to work, perhaps try a solution inside markdown-it like https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it-container or something similar.

@zachleat (11ty maintainer) created an improvement of the Render Plugin that does what I wanted: follow here
Ships in 11ty 3.0
